Neural network for matrix as input and position in matrix as output - reinforcement
I have set up a very basic environment in gymnasium, consisting on an nxn matrix, populated by 0s and 1s. The neural network now should output a vector, pointing to one specific entry of the matrix.
For now, this should simply be an entry with 0, which will then changed to 1: essentially the ai populates the matrix with 1s via reinforcement learning. Later, I want it to find approate positions to place shapes into the matrix (a bit like a Tetris game only the blocks are not falling).
Anyways, I have up to now used DQN models, which seem not to be really suitable here. Could anyone please point me to a better approach for this input/output setup?

What I have done now to get my setup working with DQN is flattening both spaces:
self.observation_space = spaces.MultiBinary(n * n)
self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(n*n)

observation space: While my state / observation space is actually matrix with 0s and 1s, I am flattening it to a MultiBinary, where true represents 1 and false represents 0. Using MultiBinary has greatly improved performance.
action_space: Similarly, while it represents a vector that point a location in the matrix location, I use a Discrete action space, which I then unflatten for backing out the entry in the matrix
    row = action // (self.n)
    col = action % (self.n)

In summary, while it was unintuitive for me, the DQN model can handle matrices in observation spaces, simply by flattening the matrix to one MultiDiscrete or MultiBinary. Also, the action of selecting an entry in a matrix can be represented by Discrete(n*n).
